# Xcode - Could not locate device support files / Failed to prepare the device for development

Tags: xcode

**iPad**
I'm currently learning Xcode (so not yet that techy!). I've connected my iPad Air 3rd gen (latest iOS version 17.2) to my Macbook Air 2017 (latest OS version 12.7.2) and when I try to run an app on Xcode (v14.2 latest version), I can select my device, but I get the message 'could not locate device support files'. Can anyone help please?

**iPhone**
The other question is when I try and connect to iPhone SE (1st gen) latest IOS v15.8, I get the message 'Failed to prepare the device for development'

I updated all OS and Xcode versions and rebooted devices.